# Twilio Autopilot, best method to check mobile number in external database

Tags: function, asynchronous, twilio, webhooks

I would like to use Twilio autopilot to build a whatsapp Chatbot. I need to know if a user has already used our service before. This means that on initiation, i get the data from an external source, i can then use functions to further specify the chatbot logic.

I am wondering what are the best options in the twilio environment to get that external data loaded in event or memory? I see webhooks are only for diagnostics, and i dont know what are the async capabilities of functions. Could someone elaborate a bit about the pro's and cons of different methods?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "on initiation"? Is that like an initial WhatsApp message to trigger a flow?

Comment: yes indeed it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at [The Autopilot Request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request). These request parameters are provided to your application (via a webhook associated with a task), where you can add additional logic to see if this is a new user or returning user and return the appropriate [Autopilot Actions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions), one of which is [Remember](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/remember).

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be setting a webhook that will determine if the User has used the system before on to the Assistant's `assistant_initiation` [more info](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api/assistant/defaults)

The webhook can then reply with a JSON [Remember](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/remember) + [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/redirect)

Example -

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "remember": {
                "isNewuser": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "redirect": "task://newUserTask"
        }
    ]
}
```

OR

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "remember": {
                "isNewuser": "false"
            }
        },
        {
            "redirect": "task://oldUserTask"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also since `"isNewuser": "true"` will be on the assistant's [memory](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request) you can use that info on any following task until the session (4 Hours) expires.